# Загрузка iframe при условии ссылки

Tags: javascript, iframe

Требуется загрузить iframe при выполнении **двух условий**:

1. Ссылка у страницы должна оканчиваться на **#help**
2. После выполнения первого условия должно пройти **2 секунды**, далее
   iframe загружается.

..#help добавляется при клике на кнопку на странице.

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: Не получается загружать фрейм по прохождению времени.

Comment: iframe начнет загружаться, когда установлен атрибут src:
setTimeout (() => iframe.src = url, 2000)